# Scrollview in a view not resoponding IOS

Tags: ios, view, scrollview, viewcontroller

I know I must be doing something incredibly silly, but I am struggling with something that should be simple.

I have a tabbar app and originally I had the viewcontroller loaded with a XIB that only contained a scrollview.  I tied the scrollview to the viewcontroller VIEW and the scrollview to a scrollview outlet and made the file owner the delegate as well.. and everything worked fine.

Then I decided to add some more elements to this view, so I created a VIEW, moved the ScrollView to be a subview of that VIEW, and added more elements.  I tied the top view to the file owners view, and the scrollview to a scrollview element in the controller one again, and made its delegate the view controller

Now, suddenly the scrollview doesn't scroll, it seems like the interactions are not getting to the scrollview or something and are being intercepted by the parent view.

I'm a bit perplexed on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into the XIB and make sure the "User Interaction" option with the scroll view is still enabled.  If it is, check the "Exclusive Touch" outlet on every view to see if they are disabled (as they should be), and enable it on the scroll view.  If all else fails, check that the content size of this thing is larger than its frame, else it won't scroll.

Comment: I dont see an "EXCLUSIVE TOUCH" outlet in the XIB editor.. Where would this be located?

Comment: You may have to set it in code.  Exclusive touch allows UIViews to force scroll views to give up touches in that area.

Comment: I figured it out, it was that I had things going on to the VIEW and the ScrollView differently in my code, when view and scrollview were the same object (first case) we were good.. Obviously when view and scrollview became 2 differing objects not everything was working properly.. so stupid human error.  Of course now I am finding that touches aren't working properly under iOS5, but work perfectly in iOS4... the fun never ends.

Comment: Of course.  I would open up another question about that little bug there.  Don't forget to upvote and accept!

Comment: CodaFi... Already added http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377333/touchesended-not-working-in-ios5-working-fine-in-ios4